# Mouse scroll sometimes doesn't work in MS Word in wine

Tags: wine, mouse, mouse-scroll

I have MS Office 2007 in wine 3.6 on Kubuntu 18.04. If I launch several Word documents, sometimes the mouse scroll stops working when switching to another document. Sometimes this issue can be solved by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> twice or by minimizing and maximizing the window, but it works until the next window switch. I've noticed that sometimes the mouse scroll affects the background window, as if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> has been pressed, i.e. changes the font size. Is there a way to solve this problem?

It doesn't work at other my machine as well, so I think there is something with `wine` or `Plasma` rather than system configuration.

Comment: If you install `inxi` and post the output of `inxi -Fxxxz` here by editing your post, people will get a better idea of your system.

Comment: It is known issue. For me it exists on all GPUs - integrated Intel, AMD APU, proprietary Nvidia. I did not find any solution.

Comment: @N0rbert Do you have any links with discussion on this problem, I didn't find any?

Comment: @MichaelO I mean for me it is known. I have not searched for it yet.

Comment: @N0rbert try my solution

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I found a working solution when stumbled upon [this](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=20006#p96540) post. First you have to do what has been said there:

> Disabling desktop effects did not help. Unchecking "Allow windows
>   manager to control the windows" had side effects (window always on
>   foreground). What works for me with Word, Excel and Powerpoint is:
>
> ```
> Start System Settings
>
> Select Window Behaviour
>
> Select Window Rules
>
> Click "New..." to create a new Window Rules
>
> Enter the description
>
> Window Class: Regular Expression. I use .*\b(winword.exe|excel.exe|powerpnt.exe)\b.*
>
> Check "Match whole window class"
>
> Check on tab "Size & Position"
>
> Check "Full screen": value Forced, No
>
> Check "Ignore Requested Geometry": value Forced, Yes
> ```

This will allow you to resize MS apps. Then go to the tab "Appearance and workaround" and do the following:

> "Prevent focus stealing" -> check -> Forced -> High priority
>
> "Focus protection" -> check -> Forced -> High priority

(don't know how exactly it is in English, my system is in another language).

Comment: It is not clear where I should do these settings... In winecfg? I cannot find "Appearance and workaround".

Comment: @cdupont About where to do those settings I found them on OpenSUSE TW which defaults to KDE. "Windows Behavior" seems to be a KDE specific option.